# has no exported member 'AngularFireModule'

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, npm, ionic2

I am working on a project with angular 2 , firebase and ionic, I installed all the npm packages and angularfire2 as well. 
But when i am using

```
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
```

when I open the app.module.ts the IDE(Visual Studio Code) says that there is no exported member called 'AngularFireModule'.

versions of the dependencies of my package.json file are

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.10.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.10.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.10.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.1",
    "firebase": "^4.1.3",
    "ionic-angular": "3.4.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^2.0.2",
    "typescript": "2.3.3"
  },
```

Is there anything missing from the package.json or the problem is with incompatible versions?

Comment: What is the "it" that is showing the error? Your IDE? Does this all compile/run? Have you closed and reopened the file?

Comment: can you please show your app.module.ts file ?

Comment: check this https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/425

Comment: Thank you for the help.. when i restart the machine the error disappeared. I guess it was because of the cache.